# Bash Script -test the content of a file with a String-

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have a file 'res.txt' which contain a result of a program, i need to test that result with a String "UNSAT" In a Bash script ! 
any help !

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading your question wrong though if not create a script for example called my_script.

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(find ./ -type f -name 'res.txt' | xargs grep "UNSAT")
echo $output
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep is your answer:

```
grep -m1 -c "UNSAT" res.txt
```

It will print `1` if the file contains "UNSAT" or `0` if not.

- The option `-m1` stops at first occurrence (avoid search entire file)
- The option `-c` print counting.